# How good is Yosemite - Is it worth to upgrade now or wait till it stabilizes

Tags: icloud, macos, software-update

I have iMac (2012) with OSX 10.9.5 (Mavericks) currently on it. I am a iOS app developer and need my mac best performing and can't let my mac go down for even 2-3 days.

I have read news about issues on Yosemite release and even some on iCloud bundled in the same. I wanted to confirm that is it stable enough to retain my work and performance of my mac as it is now.

waiting to reply from Maverick users.

EDIT for more clarifications :

I wanted more reviews specially on following sections from Mac / iOS Devloper Perspective

1. Stability
2. Performance
3. Ease of Upgrade (as it is >5GB and available on Mac App Store only, in low bandwidth intennet it may get disconnected between download)
4. Recommended features e.g security updates

-- Vishal

Comment: If your question is is Yosemite as stable as Mavericks, no it is not at this time.

Comment: FWIW, I have not had any show stoppers, but Safari and/or Mail.app tend to hog the CPU and/or RAM occasionally to the point where I have to take a few minutes to get a coffee and wait for it to stabilise. This is clearly a buggy behaviour and it *does* slow down my work occasionally, but again not to the point of being a show stopper. `</anecdotal-evidence>`

Comment: Can't comment as to stability. But I can comment as to usability. The user interface of Yosemite is dreadful. I found it so irritating and irksome that I got rid of it, and went back to Mavericks which is vastly superior. Yosemite has a distinctly un-Apple feel. If you are a Windows user, you probably won't care ... but if you are used to using Mac OS, I would say Yosemite is more than a big step backwards.

Comment: This question seems to broad now—perhaps try narrowing it down to a specific, answerable scope.

Comment: Personally I haven't had any problems with it, except for a bit of lag when windows are dragged near the top of the screen.

Comment: Regarding your edit: This site works better if you focus on one specific aspect in a question, otherwise it will be hard to see which answers do provide valuable input and which don't. See the [FAQ] for details about how to ask "good" questions.

Answer (score 3):

There are some bugs as in every .0 release, but your mileage may vary as to which ones (if any) end up affecting you. Unfortunately nobody can predict that. If you are concerned about a critical production system being put out of commission, it is probably best to wait for 10.10.1.

Answer (score 3):

If you're dependent on your computer for your livelihood, it's generally a good idea to always hold off on upgrading to a new major release *at least* until the first update has been released, which in the case with Yosemite will be 10.10.1.

Everyone has very different workflows and no one will ever be able to guarantee that *your* workflow works on a new release. A reasonable assumption that anyone can make, however, is that your workflow will be much safer after the initial bugs of said release have been fixed.